# Multirow header in dynamic jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am using dynamic jasper to create report.I need to add multiple header in the following way..

```
|            Report Title                |
 -----------------------------------------
|Start and End Date                      |
 -----------------------------------------
|Report Date 1 | Date                    |
 -----------------------------------------
|Report Date 2 | Date                    |
 -----------------------------------------
|Header 1|Header 2|Header 3|Header 4     |
 -----------------------------------------
|Data 1  |Data 2  |Data 3  |Data 4       |
```

Where Dates and columns (Headers are dynamic) are dynamic.searched a lot but could not found the answer.Does anyone know?

Comment: http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/create-jrxml-file-dynamically-using-dynamic-jasper-grails/. follow this link to add values dynamically in using jasper.